# Where do I find explanations of syntax coloring (atom, python)?

Tags: python, atom-editor, grammar

I am trying to learn Python, coming from R. I am using Atom with the dark syntax theme and I cannot find an explanation for what the syntax colors mean.

I tried:

- Many Google searches with varying combinations of the terms "one dark atom syntax coloring meaning explanation grammar python".
- Looking at the source pages for "[Atom One dark syntax theme](https://github.com/atom/one-dark-syntax)" and "[One Dark Syntax theme](https://atom.io/packages/one-dark-syntax)".
- Stack Exchange searches.

In particular, I want to know why the word "columns" is marked red in my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_sec(time_str):
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)

mydata = pd.read_csv("PATH/Activities.csv")
mydata = pd.DataFrame(mydata)

for col in mydata.columns:
    print(col)

mydata['seconds'] = mydata['Time'].apply(get_sec)
mydata = mydata[mydata['seconds'] > 600]

meanwosecs = np.mean(mydata['seconds'])

def get_time(secs):
    s = round(secs%60)
    m = int(((secs - s) / 60)%60)
    h = int((secs - m * 60 - s)/3600)
    #print(h,m,s)
    sep=':'
    return sep.join([str(h),str(m),str(s)])

print('average workout time:',get_time(meanwosecs))
```

Comment: Are you asking for recommendations and pointers to tutorials/pages, or asking for a tutorial how syntax coloring works? Either is off-topic on SO. Is there a specific problem with your attempts to solve this? Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: Thanks. 
I am asking for a pointer or a strategy to find syntax coloring for my theme. I thought it would be very easy to answer (e.g. go to such-and-such place in the documentation), but maybe not? I am trying to learn python and I thought knowing the meaning of the coloring might speed up my learning process.
About this being off-topic. I went to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and found "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". If my question does not fall under that category, maybe you can recommend a better forum for this type of question?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421 is an important read. The answer you want isn't easily answerable as SO has criteria for clear and concise questions and answers, and what you're asking covers many technologies. We don't know your level of expertise, so, to be clear we have to start with the basics in each technology and move upward, then show how they're linked together to answer you. A simple answer will be many pages worth of explanation resulting in a tutorial, and that becomes off-topic as too broad of a question.

Comment: Instead, tell us where you searched and read, then tell us what the gaps are in what you read. That way we don't have to readdress those things and won't point you to what you already read. Then, after you have done the research, try modifying your Atom config and see if it affects the color. At that point you'll have a better chance of asking a specific question about a hole in your knowledge or why something in your change didn't work. Asking for a pointer to another site is off-topic because you want recommendations to off-site resources. Yes, you'll see it happen, but they're off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the discussion. I am new here and have a lot to learn. That said, I do think that my original question adhered to a lot of the suggestions in that thread. Moreover, does not the fact you suggest "try modifying your Atom config and see if it affects the color" indicate that my original question is a good one?